# How to identify the start and end of a stream through wowza?

Tags: stream, streaming, video-streaming, wowza, wow64

I'm new in Wowza. I need to know whether there is any mechanism to identify the start and end of a stream through wowza. This service will monitor each of the inbound ports that are currently bound to wowza engine and then try to create a notification on two events. 
1. Start of UDP packets in to the port, the event should trigger everytime a new port receives packets. 
2. End of UDP packets in to the port. If no packets hit the given port for a certain period of time, this event will be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Wowza has modules and there is one that makes something similar: https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?171-How-to-use-IMediaStreamActionNotify2-to-monitor-live-streams-%28ModuleStreamWatchDog%29

the source is public so you could modify to match your needs. Java skills required.

the other way is to call the rest api periodically and check for new streams.